# Erro ao exibir mensagem no PL-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

**Código**

```
DECLARE
BEGIN

    FOR I IN (SELECT * FROM PRODUTOS_TESTE2) LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.codigo|| ' - ' || I.categoria || ' - ' || I.VALOR); 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

```
Relatório de erros -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 28:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 5, column 14:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 32:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 6, column 11:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

**Estrutura da Tabela**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Publique a estrutura de PRODUTOS_TESTES.

Comment: O nome da tabela é PRODUTOS_TESTE2 mesmo ? E tente colocar antes do nome da tabela o nome do Schema, por exemplo: "select * from nomeschema.produtos_teste2"